# mysql query with subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have one mysql table that contains names of people (id, name) and another one with the presences in training sessions (id_training, id_person, date).
I need to do a mysql query to know the people who were not present in any training session on the last two months from today.
Many thanks for the help.

Comment: You don't need a subquery, you need a join.  Read up!  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.name
FROM people AS p
LEFT JOIN training AS t
ON p.id = t.id_person
AND date > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
WHERE t.id_person IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `training sessions.id_person` a foreign key of the primary key in people, people.id? Also, what is the datatype for the date attribute in training seasons? If it's in total days, then 
you'll want to do something like this:

```
SELECT people.id, people.name
FROM people, training sessions
WHERE training sessions.id_person = people.id AND where training sessions.date !< 60
```